# Why does release pipeline set authentication for entire site, instead of application

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline using the IIS web app deploy template.

The IIS Web site is set to "Default Web Site" and the virtual application is set to "MyApp"

After the release pipeline executes, if I look at the log for the IIS Web App Manage task it appears that it is setting the authentication on the default web site, not at the web application level.  It also appears to be setting the specified app pool as the default for the web site, when I want that done at the virtual application level, because there are other web applications on that site that I don't want to affect.  Is there some way to make these settings at the app level, not the web site level?

Here is the full log:

```
2022-02-10T16:16:53.9186563Z ##[section]Starting: IIS Web App Manage
2022-02-10T16:16:53.9300577Z ==============================================================================
2022-02-10T16:16:53.9300909Z Task         : IIS web app manage
2022-02-10T16:16:53.9301223Z Description  : Create or update websites, web apps, virtual directories, or application pools
2022-02-10T16:16:53.9301492Z Version      : 0.198.0
2022-02-10T16:16:53.9301696Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-02-10T16:16:53.9302045Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group
2022-02-10T16:16:53.9302418Z ==============================================================================
2022-02-10T16:16:55.4449893Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list apppool /name:"MyAppPool"
2022-02-10T16:16:55.5231443Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set apppool /apppool.name:"MyAppPool" -managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0 -managedPipelineMode:Integrated -processModel.identityType:ApplicationPoolIdentity
2022-02-10T16:16:55.5956233Z APPPOOL object "MyAppPool" changed
2022-02-10T16:16:55.6061768Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list site /name:"Default Web Site"
2022-02-10T16:16:55.6749812Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"Default Web Site" -applicationDefaults.applicationPool:"MyAppPool" -[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:"%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" -[path='/'].[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].[path='/'].password:
2022-02-10T16:16:55.7530677Z SITE object "Default Web Site" changed
2022-02-10T16:16:55.7764117Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list sites
2022-02-10T16:16:55.8552169Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config "Default Web Site" /section:anonymousAuthentication /enabled:true /commit:apphost
2022-02-10T16:16:55.9337334Z Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
2022-02-10T16:16:55.9487302Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config "Default Web Site" /section:basicAuthentication /enabled:false /commit:apphost
2022-02-10T16:16:56.0248364Z Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
2022-02-10T16:16:56.0350346Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config "Default Web Site" /section:windowsAuthentication /enabled:true /commit:apphost
2022-02-10T16:16:56.1203530Z Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
2022-02-10T16:16:56.1812060Z ##[section]Finishing: IIS Web App Manage
```

**Edit**

I was able to get it to stop setting at the web site level by changing the pipeline stage configuration type from IIS WebSite to IIS Web Application.  However, there is no place to specify the authentication type(s) to use for the web application with that configuration type.

**Edit 2**
I just realized that when the configuration type is set to IIS Web Application, it deploys the web application files directly into wwwroot, instead of into wwwroot\MyApp